# PSQLException: ERROR: while storing PostgreSQL data into CSV file

Tags: java, postgresql, csv, rdbms

I am using PostgreSQL DB and Java. I am trying to store the PostgreSQL data into the CSV file through the following LoC.

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Copy (select * from tableName where condition limit 10) To 'pathName/fileName.csv' With CSV DELIMITER ','");
```

But the above LoC gives the following error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: must be superuser to COPY to or from a file
Hint: Anyone can COPY to stdout or from stdin. psql's \copy command also works for anyone.
```

Any suggestions or help?

Comment: You can use [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#writing) to write to a CSV file

Comment: Please also share what you've tried so far. Which error message are you getting with your script?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question show us your Java code that generates the CSV file as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362), [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) please. Why can't you just write two columns to the CSV file?